# ElephantIO inside thread does not work

Tags: php, multithreading, socket.io

Having pthreads installed on my php 5.6, I am unable to run ElephantIO inside a thread.

```
<?php

require( __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X;

class workerThread extends Thread {

    public function __construct($i) {
        $this->i = $i;
    }

    public function run() {

        $client = new Client(new Version1X('http://localhost:3000'));
        $client->initialize();

        while (true) {
            $client->emit('chat message', ["[$i] Now is" . microtime()]);
            sleep(5);
        }

        $client->close();
    }

}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $workers[$i] = new workerThread("User $i");
    $workers[$i]->start();
}

echo "Done";
```

Even if I add `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`, errors would still not show that occur in the thread (I added it at the start of `run()` and at the start of the script.

However, by echoing, I realized that the error occurs at line 98 of `Version1X.php` which is:

```
$payload = new Encoder($code . $message, Encoder::OPCODE_TEXT, true);
```

Do you have any ideas how can I solve this?

Note: It does work outside the thread.

Comment: HTH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799591/elephant-io-client-not-working

Comment: Quite irrelevant since it works out of the thread

Comment: Have you looked inside the Encoder ? Can't see what's wrong. Would you mind creating an issue on the github repository ? Thanks.